# PythonでExcelに画像挿入したい

Tags: python, python3

**やりたいこと：**
Pythonで[WEB](https://shoply.co.jp/4953103354739%E3%81%AE%E4%BE%A1%E6%A0%BC%E3%81%A8%E6%9C%80%E5%AE%89%E5%80%A4)から「最安値」の商品を取得して画像を
Excelに画像挿入したいです。

下記のコードで**requests**のライブラリー
を使って画像ファイル保存してからエクセルへ貼りけています。
ただ画像セルには番号しかエクセルへ貼り付けられないです。

エクセル
※値にはJAN_CODEのみ記載その他空白です。
JAN_CODEから検索して画像などを取得しています。

| JAN_CODE | 画像 | 商品名 | 実勢価格 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4953103354739 |  |  |  |

**現在エクセルの結果**

| JAN_CODE | 画像 | 商品名 | 実勢価格 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4953103354739 | **47363** | ET-IQCL1L エレコム 電子タバコ IQOS 専用 クリーニングスティック 100本 | ¥530 |

保存した画像をセル内に挿入する方法ありますでしょうか。
もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけると嬉しいです。

全体のコード

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import requests

#ファイル名
file=r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.xlsx"

#エクセル読み込み
df = pd.read_excel(file)
#読み込みエクセル指定
df_JAN_CODE = df["JAN_CODE"]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

#1行ずつ読み込み
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    #url指定
    #url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+row.JAN_CODE
    url="https://shoply.co.jp/"+str(row.JAN_CODE).replace(".0","")+"の価格と最安値"
    
    #検索サイトを開く
    driver.get(url)
    
    #5秒待機
    time.sleep(5)

    #画像取得
    gazou=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result-list"]/ul/li[1]/div/a/div[3]/img')
    print(gazou)

    img_url = gazou.get_attribute('src')

    #画像保存
    file_name = "test.jpg"

    response = requests.get(img_url)
    image = response.content

    with open(file_name, "wb") as aaa:
     aaa.write(image)

     #画像をエクセルへ貼り付け
     df.loc[index,'画像']=aaa.write(image)

    #商品名取得
    shyohinmai=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result-list"]/ul/li[1]/div/a/div[4]/span[2]').text
    print(shyohinmai)

    df.loc[index,'商品名']=shyohinmai

    #価格取得
    kakaku=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result-list"]/ul/li[1]/div/a/div[5]/span').text
    print(kakaku)

    df.loc[index,'実勢価格']=kakaku

    #xlsx書き出し
    df.to_excel(file, sheet_name="sheet", index=False, header=True)

driver.close()
```

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: VBAの記事を探して、それを基にPythonに変換してみてはどうでしょう？ [Excel VBA:セルに合わせて図形/画像オブジェクト(シェイプ)を移動する、セルと同じサイズに変更するサンプルプログラム](https://selifelog.com/blog-entry-1470.html), [Excel VBA:画像ファイルの画像を指定したセルのサイズを合わせて貼り付けるサンプルプログラム](https://selifelog.com/blog-entry-1614.html), [ダブルクリックでセルに画像を貼りつける（Pictures.Insertメソッド）](https://www.moug.net/tech/exvba/0120027.html), [VBA100本ノック 29本目：画像の挿入](https://excel-ubara.com/vba100/VBA100_029.html)

Comment: 「画像の保存」と「画像の貼り付け」で手順を分割して、どこが問題なのかをまず切り分けるべきだと思います。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。
こちらの`Openpyxl`方法で出来そうなので、試してみます。
https://kirinote.com/python-excel-imageadd/